# Reduction of complement from complexity class co-np and p

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes, co-np

Let P $ \neq $ NP.
D is in the complexity class co-NP.
B is in the complexity class P.
Let $ \bar{D} $ be the complement of D, then $\bar{D} $ $\leq _ {p} $ B.

Is this statement true or false? My guess is that it's wrong because D is $ \in $ co-NP and therefore $\bar{D} $ is $ \in $ NP. From the reduction $\bar{D}$ $ \leq_ {p} $B, it would follow that P = NP, which contradicts  to the assumption.

Is that correct or am I having a mistake?

Comment: D and B could just be in P.

Comment: Can you explain why D could be in P? Does that mean if  D is in co-np, that the complement of D is not in NP?

Comment: @x_x Because D is simply in coNP, not *coNP-complete*.

Comment: But isn't coNP all problems, that have a complement in NP?